# Set default style to listviewitem

Tags: wpf, xaml

Everytime `listviewitem` gets selected, automatically its foreground gets set to `white`.

How can I prevent this behavior in codebehind?

I tried this, but without effect:

```
 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" > or True
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to change the foreground color of your ListItem when the item is selected?

Comment: I changed the text a bit for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly answer the question, because there is no code behind in this solution. But in my opinion, code behind is not the way to go here.

```
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
   ...
  <Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Some color"/>
     </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```